# MonoTouch return a string from a Task

Tags: xamarin.ios, task

I am using following code to call a web service in update UI using Task

```
//------- REFRESH BOOK LIST ------
    public Task<string> GetBookList()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {

            // GET BOOK LIST
            WebServiceController webServices = new WebServiceController ();
            string bookList = webServices.GetBookList ();

            if (bookList.Contains("BooksList")) {

                // PARSE
                ParseListData parseData = new ParseListData ();
                parseData.ParseList (bookList);

            }
                            return bookList;

        });

    }
```

I call this code using

```
GetBookList ().ContinueWith (task => {

    if (task.IsFaulted) {
        // STOP ACTIVITY INDICATOR
        RemoveActivityIndicator (true);

        throw new AggregateException (task.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }

    // RUNS WHEN TASK IS FINISHED
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            // STOP ACTIVITY INDICATOR
            RemoveActivityIndicator (true);
            string bookList = task.Result;
            if (bookList.Contains("Error:") || !bookList.Contains("BooksList"))
                    {
                     // SHOW ERROR MESSAGE

                    }
                });

            });
```

If there is an error in the return string (bookList) then i want to check for bookList.Contains("Error:") as above and show error message. The problem in that is bookList string is assigned in the Task GetBookList() function. How do i get that value in GetBookList ().ContinueWith to show error.

How to write a Task in above situation to return a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Task<string>`, then the Task's Result property can be used to store your String value.

Comment: I got what you are saying but how to apple it in above context. Can you specify where exactly i need to change that.

Comment: Change `public Task GetBookList()` to `public Task<string> GetBookList()`. Then in the method, actually return the string: `return someString;`.

Comment: I have modified the code as mentioned above but it is throwing error saying "Cann't implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> " at GetBookList ().ContinueWith (task => {. See my code above

Comment: try `ContinueWith<string>`